# Ошибка в aiogram: Chat not found

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть код в котором я хочу отослать сообщение другому пользователю на его id, но он не запускал его у себя(не нажимал /start) как это можно обойти и что с эти можно сделать
код:

```
async def sendall(message: types.Message):
    #if message.from_user.id == 629193195:
    text = 'abcd'
    id = '515949536'
    await bot.send_message(id, text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Никак. Боты не могут слать кому-либо сообщения в личку, пока с ними не заведут беседу

Comment: а как тогда работают рассылки на питоне

Comment: Конкретизируйте какие именно рассылки. Если от человека к человеку, но скриптом, то это можно сделать через api менеджера телеграмма ([пример с выводом диалогов](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/eaae662636fac822d2b92f889df7a5f56db3dcbe/telegram__telethon__examples/print_dialogs.py))

Comment: Если от бота к человеку, то в этом случае человек должен первый взаимодействовать с ботом, см. https://core.telegram.org/bots#4-how-are-bots-different-from-humans а именно `Bots can't initiate conversations with users. A user must either add them to a group or send them a message first. People can use t.me/<bot_username> links or username search to find your bot.`

Comment: спасибо вам буду знать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Даю ответ на вопрос
Для того чтобы бот мог отправлять сообщение пользователю, пользователь должен первым обратиться к боту. В этот момент код должен сохранить ид пользователя чтобы знать что ему можно отправить сообщение. Если юзер не обращался к боту то и бот не может отправить юзеру сообщение.